# limit of a function with a variable as exponent

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am trying to calculate this limit $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[{x^a}\bigg[\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt x}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\bigg]\right]$$ when $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

anyone have an idea

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[{x^a}\bigg[\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt x}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\bigg]\right]=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[{x^a}\bigg[\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x-2}-\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\sqrt{ x^2+2x}}\bigg]\right]$$$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-2x^a}{\sqrt{ x^2+2x}\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+x-2}+\sqrt{x^2+x}\bigg)}$$ which is equal to $-1$ if $a=2$, equals zero when $a<2$ and minus infinity when $a>2$.

Comment: do you mind explaining the last transition that you have done?

Comment: certainly. Multiplying  the denominator by its conjugate and taking  each $x^2$ term outside of square root. .

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}}=\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{1/2}=1-\frac1{2x}-\frac1{8x^2}+O(x^{-3})$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}=\left(\frac{1+x^{-1}}{1+2x^{-1}}\right)^{1/2}=\left(1-\frac1{x}+\frac2{x^2}+O(x^3)\right)
=1-\frac1{2x}+\frac{7}{8x^2}+O(x^{-3})$$
and so
$$\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}}-
\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}=-\frac1{x^2}+O(x^{-3}).$$

Thus we only get an interesting limit when $a=2$...

Answer (score 0):

In the limit, any rational function behaves like a power of $x$, let $b$, and the whole expression will be asymptotic to $x^{a-b}$.

Let us try to evaluate this $b$:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt x}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac{(x-1)(x+2)-x(x+1)}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}\right)}.$$

For large $x$, ignoring the low order terms, this tends to

$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt x\sqrt x(\sqrt x\sqrt x+\sqrt x\sqrt x)}.$$